# Angular 2 Reactive Forms - How to show the FormArray controls different than input element

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to use `FormArray` with elements other than `input` element. Most of the examples I've seen uses `input` element as the dynamically presented objects.

In the component I've added the `FormArray`.

```
newHobby: string = null;
employmentForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      'hobbies': new FormArray([])
    });
}

onAddHobby() {
    const control = new FormControl(this.newHobby, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.employmentForm.get('hobbies')).push(control);
}
```

And in the html,

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
    <div class="form-group" formArrayName="hobbies">
        <input type="text" id="new-hobby" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newHobby" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mt-3" type="button" (click)="onAddHobby()">Add Hobby</button>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"
            *ngFor="let hobbyControl of userForm.get('hobbies').controls; let i = index"
            [formControlName]="i" [innerHtml]="hobbyControl[i]"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

But whenever I'm trying to add a hobby, by clicking the `Add Hobby` button I'm seeing the following error.

[image: FormArray Error]

Can you please point out, where am I doing wrong. Or `FormArray` does not support controls other than `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the value use "value". You can use

```
  <li class="list-group-item"
    *ngFor="let hobbyControl of userForm.get('hobbies').controls; let i = index"
    [formControlName]="i" [innerHtml]="hobbyControl[i].value"></li>
```

But you can also use

```
  <li class="list-group-item"
    *ngFor="let hobbyValue of userForm.get('hobbies').value; let i = index"
    [innerHtml]="hobbyValue"></li>
```

See that userForm.get('hobbies').value is an array

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually the second option worked. Somehow the `[formControlName]="i"` is having problem and showing the same error. Here the intention is to show the values, so the second option is quite appropriate.